# Celery in dockerized django project

Tags: django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have a django project consisting of blog, article and comment applications. Comment model has a generic relation to Article model from article app and Entry from blog app. I want the two models (Entry and Article) to show the number of comments. In order to do this I have overridden `save()`, `update()` and `delete()` methods (the last is handled by a signal) which call a specific task that handles the update.

Now to the code.
`comments/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey

from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

from comments.tasks import update_comment_count_on_related_writing


class CommentManager(models.query.QuerySet):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        comments_for_previous_writings = dict()
        for comment in self.all().prefetch_related('writing_object'):
            comments_for_previous_writings[comment] = {
                'writing_pk': comment.writing_id,
                'writing_type_pk': comment.writing_type.pk
            }

        rows = super().update(**kwargs)
        for comment in self.all():
            update_comment_count_on_related_writing.delay(
                comment.pk,
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_pk'],
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_type_pk']
            )
        return rows


class Comment(TimeStampedModel):
    body = models.TextField()
    __writing_type_choices = (
            models.Q(app_label='article', model='article') | models.Q(app_label='blog', model='entry'))
    writing_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=__writing_type_choices)
    writing_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    writing_object = GenericForeignKey('writing_type', 'writing_id')

    objects = CommentManager.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '({}) {} - {}...'.format(self.writing_type, self.writing_object, self.body[:15])

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        old_writing = None
        old_writing_pk = None
        old_writing_type_pk = None

        created = not self.id
        if not created:
            # Trick used to avoid changing old_writing* references after update in order to allow introducing changes
            # to previously assigned writing.
            comment_before_update = Comment.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            old_writing = comment_before_update.writing_object
            old_writing_type_pk = comment_before_update.writing_type.pk
            old_writing_pk = old_writing.pk

        super().save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None)

        if created or old_writing != self.writing_object:
            update_comment_count_on_related_writing.delay(self.pk, old_writing_pk, old_writing_type_pk)
```

`comments/signals.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Comment
from comments.tasks import update_comment_count_on_related_writing


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Comment)
def update_writings_comments_count(instance: Comment, **_):
    update_comment_count_on_related_writing.delay(
        old_writing_pk=instance.writing_id,
        old_writing_type_pk=instance.writing_type.pk
    )
```

`article/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

from comments.models import Comment
from common.models import WritingBase


class Article(WritingBase):
    comments = GenericRelation(
        Comment, related_query_name='articles', object_id_field='writing_id', content_type_field='writing_type')
```

`blog/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

from comments.models import Comment
from common.models import WritingBase


class Entry(WritingBase):
    comments = GenericRelation(
        Comment, related_query_name='entries', object_id_field='writing_id', content_type_field='writing_type')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entries'
```

Task that handles update - `comments/tasks.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from wiktor.celery import app


@app.task
def update_comment_count_on_related_writing(updated_comment_pk=None, old_writing_pk=None, old_writing_type_pk=None):
    from comments.models import Comment
    if updated_comment_pk is not None:
        updated_comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=updated_comment_pk)
        comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(
            writing_type=updated_comment.writing_type, writing_id=updated_comment.writing_id
        ).count()
        updated_comment.writing_object._meta.model.objects.filter(
            id=updated_comment.writing_object.id
        ).update(comments_count=comments_count)

    if old_writing_pk is not None:
        old_writing_class = ContentType.objects.get(pk=old_writing_type_pk).model_class()
        comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(
            writing_type__pk=old_writing_type_pk, writing_id=old_writing_pk).count()
        old_writing_class.objects.filter(pk=old_writing_pk).update(
            comments_count=comments_count)
```

Configuration - `wiktor/celery.py`:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'wiktor.settings')

app = Celery('wiktor')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And part of settings responsible for celery:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq//'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq//'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'wiktor_queue'
```

Since everything works in docker here goes dockerfile for main service Django works in:

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements/base.txt requirements/dev.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r base.txt -r dev.txt
ADD . /code/
RUN celery -A wiktor worker -D
WORKDIR /code
```

And docker-compose config (named `dev.yml`):

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.6-alpine
  postgres:
    image: postgres
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - elasticsearch
      - rabbitmq
```

Now, the code part is over let's get to how it currently works.

I start the project with `docker-compose -f dev.yml up --build`. In admin panel I see that a Comment is assigned to a specific Entry

[image]

Entry that this comment is related to has 2 comments:

[image]

I change `writing type` field in Comment from Entry to Article, click save and continue editing and refresh Entry edit page. The comment count remains 2.

From logs it seems that rabbitmq did not receive this task:

```
rabbitmq_1       | 2018-07-11 08:53:51.822 [info] <0.640.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.640.0> (172.18.0.5:56766 -> 172.18.0.2:5672)
rabbitmq_1       | 2018-07-11 08:53:51.825 [info] <0.640.0> connection <0.640.0> (172.18.0.5:56766 -> 172.18.0.2:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:53:51] "POST /admin/comments/comment/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:53:51] "GET /admin/comments/comment/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5756
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:53:51] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:53:51] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:54:34] "GET /admin/blog/entry/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5928
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:54:34] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:55:30] "POST /admin/comments/comment/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
django_1         | [11/Jul/2018 08:55:30] "GET /admin/comments/comment/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5748
```

I have also ensured that there is no problem with my logic, only with celery by deleting calls to `delay`, so that

```
update_comment_count_on_related_writing.delay(
                comment.pk,
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_pk'],
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_type_pk']
            )
```

became

```
update_comment_count_on_related_writing(
                comment.pk,
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_pk'],
                comments_for_previous_writings[comment]['writing_type_pk']
            )
```

and in this case after saving Comment and refreshing page I saw that the comment_count got updated.

Now finally the question: what do I have to do to make comment_count autoupdate to reflect actual comments count?